# Order by and group by mysql not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

oke this is wat i want

Database

```
id | fromm | ontvanger | date | msg | gelezen
--------------------------------------------------
1  | kees  | marc     | time_stamp  | 0
1  | hans  | marc     | time_stamp  | 1
3  | kees  | marc     | time_stamp  | 0
5  | selma | marc     | time_stamp  | 1
6  | kees  | marc     | time_stamp  | 0
7  | kees  | marc     | time_stamp  | 0
```

this is wat i want GROUP BY fromm

```
1  | hans  | marc     | time_stamp  | 1
3  | kees  | marc     | time_stamp  | 0
5  | selma | marc     | time_stamp  | 1

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM berichten where ontvanger = '$session->username' 
GROUP BY fromm ORDER BY date DESC
");
```

Show the latest record and gelezen is 0 first

Comment: Umm post the desired result.

Comment: in results it shows the first post of hans kees and selma. i want the latest record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    berichten  a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  fromm, MAX(date) date
            FROM    berichten
            GROUP   BY fromm
        ) b ON  a.fromm = b.fromm AND
                a.date = b.date
WHERE   a.ontvanger = '$session->username'
ORDER   BY (gelezen = 0) DESC, id
```

The subquery lets you get the *latest* `date` for each `fromm`. The result of it is then joined back on the original table to get the other values of the columns.

`(gelezen = 0)` results in a boolean value that if it is true will give `1` otherwise `0`. Since you want to order the row based on `gelezen = 0`, apply a descending order on the result of boolean arithmetic.